# What version of Angular were components introduced in and how do they differ from directives?

Tags: angularjs

What version of Angular were components introduced in and how do they differ from directives?

Are they simply another name for directives, or do they have a different lifecycle/API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [SitePoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/upgrade-to-angular-components/) you got components from **Angular 1.5** and above.

Further you can read up the exact differences between directives and components in the official [AngularJS - Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> In AngularJS, a Component is a special kind of directive that uses a
>   simpler configuration which is suitable for a component-based
>   application structure.

Here some advantages and disatvantages of components:

**Advantages of Components:**

- simpler configuration than plain directives
- promote sane defaults and best practices
- optimized for component-based architecture
- writing component directives will make it easier to upgrade to Angular

**When not to use Components:**

- for directives that need to perform actions in compile and pre-link functions, because they aren't available
- when you need advanced directive definition options like priority, terminal, multi-element
- when you want a directive that is triggered by an attribute or CSS class, rather than an element

For further reading please refer to the [Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: Thats exactly same as my answer you were just few seconds late in posting this :P

Comment: @Manish Well I guess I was not fast enough :3

Comment: @Manish the sad thing is the answer with a link only gets upvoted, I mean what the heck?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in that case. Thats How things work on the contrary you will get downvotes Sometimes if you post a link. Different people different perspectives.

Comment: Any ways removed mine and upvoted this. No point in having two duplicate answers. :)

Comment: @Manish I find this very generous of you pal (y) !!